# How to pass returned object of function A as an argument to function B?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to pass `function getCoordinates`'s returned object literal (which are longitude and latitude coordinates) to `function getWeather` in the form of an argument so I am able to access `function getCoordinates`'s object literal in `function getWeather`. Or in other words, I am looking to pass the output of one function as the input to another function so I am able to access it's data. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Here's my JavaScript code so far:

```
var APP = {
    getCoordinates: function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var coordinates = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                }
                return coordinates;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation isn't supported in your browser.");
        }
    },

    getWeather: function (getCoordinates) {
        var api_key = '1234567890',
            weather_query = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/';
            weather_query += api_key + '/geolookup/q/';
            weather_query += longitude + ',' + latitude + '.json';
    }
}
```

Comment: A nitpick: a *literal* is the source-code representation of a value. A function doesn't return a literal, it returns a *value* (such as an object).

Comment: Can't you just evaluate `getCoordinates` inside `getWeather`?

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so `return` isn't really an option. Have you tried adjusting `getCoordinates` to accept and call a `callback` of its own?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, promises and deferreds works great for this.

Comment: @adeneo - I'm not using jQuery just pure vanilla JavaScript. For something like this, is it really necessary to bring in jQuery or can it be accomplished with vanilla easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var APP = {
    getCoordinates: function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getWeather);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation isn't supported in your browser.");
        }
    },
    getWeather: function (position) {
        var latitude       = position.coords.latitude,
            longitude      = position.coords.longitude,
            api_key        = '1234567890',
            weather_query  = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/';
            weather_query += api_key + '/geolookup/q/';
            weather_query += longitude + ',' + latitude + '.json';

        // do weather lookup here, inside success handler of
        // the geolocation call
    }
}

APP.getCoordinates();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzPub/4/)

Comment: I would say this is the best answer, except for adding an unnecessary framework when the user does not really need jQuery.

Comment: @zz3599 - I can't use jQuery...It has to be pure vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: removed jQuery, now just plain JS.

Answer (score 1):

Just `return`ing coordinates will not do anything. You have to accept a callback parameter:

```
var APP = {
    // Get the coordinates, and then do something with them
    getCoordinates: function (callback) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var coordinates = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                }
                // Coordinates are ready, pass to the processing function
                callback(coordinates);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation isn't supported in your browser.");
        }
    },

    getWeather: function (coordinates) {
        var api_key = '1234567890',
            weather_query = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/';
            weather_query += api_key + '/geolookup/q/';
            weather_query += coordinates.longitude + ',' + coordinates.latitude + '.json';
    }
}

APP.getCoordinates(APP.getWeather);
```

Comment: This kind of worked, however; I'm receiving the following output when I console.log(weather_query) it: http://api.wunderground.com/api/0142ba544a593cec/geolookup/q/undefined,undefined.json

Comment: @Matt - look at the URL in that query. See the problem?

Comment: `longitude` and `latitude` need a `getCoordinates.` before them.  (Though i'd strongly suggest a better name, like `coordinates`.)

Comment: Ah, the original `getWeather` had another mistake.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - I see that the long/lat are both undefined, is this because geolocation is async and it didn't actually have a chance to fetch from API?

Comment: @Matt: this was because `getWeather` ignored its parameter.

Comment: @Matt - I would expect that is the problem. As several of the answers describe, you need to do this work from the callback function, not at an arbitrary time which may be before the callback has done its work.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is impossible. So you need to rethink it. Note that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` takes a callback function. This means, as @JonathanLonowski pointed out, that the function is *asynchronous*. That is, the callback function is called later in time, whenever the value passed to it becomes available.

Returning a value from this callback doesn't do any good. What you need to do instead is do any required actions within that callback, or in another function that the callback calls (essentially the same thing).

What code calls `getWeather()`? That's the code you're going to need to look at. Instead of just making that call at an arbitrary time, the call should be made from the `getCurrentPosition()` callback, and whatever you do with `weather_query` should be done then and there.

As the code sits right now, `getWeather()` doesn't actually *do* anything. It creates a couple of local variables that are then discarded. So this may be the next issue to look at.

Whatever you do, the bottom line is the same: any action that depends on the `coordinates` from the `getCurrentPosition()` callback needs to take place at the time that callback gets called.

As @adeneo mentioned, there are tools such as jQuery's promises that you can use to help write cleaner code to do this. But no tool will change the fundamental problem: You have to wait until the data is ready, and one way or another this will amount to taking action either directly or indirectly from that callback.

Answer (score 1):

Adeneo has a great answer. Just to supplement it:

Let's change `getCoordinates` so that it now takes a callback that can do whatever processing you want on the location data.

```
getCoordinates: function (callback) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation isn't supported in your browser.");
        }
    },
```

Now, all getWeather has to do is provide that callback function.

```
getWeather: function () {
        var callback = function(position){
            var coordinates = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
             };
            var api_key = '1234567890',
            weather_query = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/';
            weather_query += api_key + '/geolookup/q/';
            weather_query += coordinates.longitude + ',' + coordinates.latitude + '.json';
            console.log(weather_query);
        };
        APP.getCoordinates(callback);

    }
```

You can continue using `APP.getWeather` to get your data. This pattern can be extended for any other sorts of processing you need to do with the location data.

Comment: Sounds great, but how do you call the local variable callback from another property in an object literal ?

Comment: I don't see why it is needed. The point is that each function provides a custom callback.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like so? See changes in function `getWeather()`.

```
var APP = {
    getCoordinates: function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var coordinates = {
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude
                }
                return coordinates;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation isn't supported in your browser.");
        }
    },

    getWeather: function (coordinates) {
        var api_key = '1234567890',
            weather_query = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/';
            weather_query += api_key + '/geolookup/q/';
            weather_query += coordinates.longitude + ',' + coordinates.latitude + '.json';
    }
}

// function call:

APP.getWeather(APP.getCoordinates());
```

Comment: But isn't _.getCurrentPosition()_ asynchronous?

Comment: That was my first thought, too -- you can't see it, but I have a deleted answer saying much the same thing -- but as Jonathan Lonowski points out in a comment to the question, `APP.getCoordinates()` doesn't actually return the coordinates; rather, it launches an asynchronous function call, and the passed-in callback returns the coordinates. (Uselessly, since nothing ever sees the callback's return-value.)

Comment: This does not work. `getCurrentPosition` returns the position asynchronously through the callback. There is no guarantee that `getWeather` even receives any coordinates.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work...but this is along the lines of what I  was thinking.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a callback function, like

```
var APP = {
    getCoordinates: function (cb) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(cb);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation isn't supported in your browser.");
        }
    },

    getWeather: function () {
        this.getCoordinates(function(cord){
            var api_key = '1234567890',
            weather_query = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/';
            weather_query += api_key + '/geolookup/q/';
            weather_query += cord.longitude + ',' + cord.latitude + '.json';

            // now you have it
            console.log(weather_query);
        });
    }
}
APP.getWeather();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/uDuVW/1/)